# Group events by day with has_many :dates association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a Events model which has many Dates.

I am listing the next weeks events and would like to group the events by day and only show the published events. I have the following code and it works but it still includes the unpublished events.

```
 Date.all.group_by {|d| d.date.at_beginning_of_day }.each do |datestr, dates|
```

Ideally I would like to have something like this...

```
@events = Event.find(:all, :conditions => {:published => true})
@events.group_all_dates_by_day.each do |datestr, dates|
```

How would I do this?

**EDIT**

This is what I would like to do but I don't like the code.

```
@events = Event.find(:all, :conditions => {:published => true})
ids = @events.map { |event| event.dates.map { |date| date.id }.join.to_i}

Date.find(ids).group_by {|date| date.date.at_beginning_of_day }
```

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this:

```
@published_events = Event.select("events.*, dates.date AS date_of_event")
     .joins(:dates)                    # you join dates table to sort the events by date
     .where(:published => true)        # here you take only published events
     .order("dates.date ASC")         # here you order them
```

In your views you'll do something like

```
@published_events.each do |event|
   <p><%= event.id %></p>
   <p><%= event.name %></p>
   <p><%= event.date_of_event %></p>
end
```

Caution -> You did not specify the exact name of your columns so I'm guessing that you event has a name, or your dates table has a column call date.

I hope this is useful!

Edit: 
   If you want to group them by date, after you retrieve them from the database (this is very important ), you could indeed use `group_by` ( [group by is located in Enumerable/group_by](http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/group_by) ) like this

```
@published_events.all.group_by(&:date_of_event)
```

If you do like this you will end up with a hash where every key is a date, and the coresponding value for that key is an array of events

Comment: Thanks so far... that displays them in order of date, but can the events be grouped into days using group_by?